# Working of a simplecursoradapter

Tags: android, cursor, simplecursoradapter, android-context

```
Cursor c = managedQuery(People.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,People.NAME);
String[] cols = new String[]{People.NAME};
int[] views = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,c,cols,views);
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I'm using this code snippet to connect my `ListView` with `Cursor`.

I want to ask what

```
String[] cols = new String[]{People.NAME};
int[] views = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
```

exactly does ??

and please explain about the arguments required for the constructor of `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a map, telling the adapter which columns from your cursor to use to fill which Widgets in your layout.

They get used in the order given.  The data in the first column listed in the from array ( you called it cols ) will go into the first id listed in the to array ( you called it views),  and so on.

The other parameters are the layout containing the view ids your specify in the to array and the cursor containing the data to be used in the array.

Answer (score 0):

**list_item.xml** Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

**HelloListView.java**

```
public class HelloListView extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, getNames()));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
}
private ArrayList<String> getNames(){
        ArrayList<String> namesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
        String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME};
        Cursor names = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        int indexName = names.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        names.moveToFirst();
        do {
            namesArray.add(names.getString(indexName));
         } while (names.moveToNext());
       return namesArray;
    }
}
```